# Pydev debugger error - NameError: name 'psort' is not defined

Tags: eclipse, debugging, pydev

I am getting an error message from Pydev in the Eclipse Console window when debugging Python code. The same error message repeats every time the debugger pauses:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "NameError: name 'psort' is not defined"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bill\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_9.2.0.202110311311\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_process_net_command.py", line 63, in process_net_command
    cmd = on_command(py_db, cmd_id, seq, text)
  File "C:\Users\Bill\.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_9.2.0.202110311311\pysrc\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_process_net_command.py", line 367, in _cmd_exec_or_evaluate_expression
    trim_if_too_big = int(trim) == 1
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "NameError: name 'psort' is not defined"
```

This is not a bug in my own code, and I don't know how to fix it. I can't tell if is my configuration or a Pydev bug, or what?  The debugger still works, but the console window gets filled up with those repeated messages.
I have been tolerating it for some months, thinking I just had to update Pydev, but I finally updated Pydev today(11/2021) and I still get the error messages.

I am using:
Windows 10 64bit
Eclipse IDE for C/C++, Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0), Build id: 20201210-1552
The Pydev version I updated to today:
Pydev version 9.2.0.20211031131

Answer (score 0):

I may have solved this, or at least a very similar looking problem. I think it was caused by some references in the Eclipse 'Expressions' view. I had let many expressions accumulate in the Expressions View. Some referenced deleted variables, out of scope variables, or variables whose definitions had changed - so expressions using them may have been buggy.

I stopped the errors by removing all of the expressions in the 'Expressions' view. I was then able to add expressions again without causing the error.

Sorry to say, I didn't identify the problem expression(s), so I didn't get to find out how they caused the problem.